# Compile manuscript with image references on own page after first reference?

Tags: scrivener

I'm working on a manuscript and to submit it, my editor wants any figures on their own page immediately following the page in the text where they are first referenced. And if there are e.g. 3 figure references on a page, to print each on its own page following the page of text in which referenced (so 1 page text followed immediately by 3 pages of figures).

Is there a way to achieve this in Scrivener compile?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, as far as I know, in Scrivener compile.

I'd suggest getting your manuscript to XML.

Then for each page extract the references to a dictionary, with the key being the page number and the value being a list of the references. Append or insert pages starting from the back (i.e. the last original page) so you know for sure you won't mess up the page numbers.